# Flow Field Character

Tags: computer-vision

Can someone give a layman's explanation of the term *flow field character* in relation to computer vision? I'm getting the term from this [paper](http://www.inb.uni-luebeck.de/publikationen/pdfs/TiBa11b.pdf).

I've only been able to find information about people using flow fields, not about what they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not so complicated. If you are familiar with an [image gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_gradient) you will realize that there is a component for the horizontal axis (Gx) and another one for the vertical axis (Gy). The final magnitud is given by sqr(Gx*Gx + Gy*Gy), but also you can find the phase angle of the gradient by applying angle=atan(Gy/Gx). With the magnitud and the angle you now have the flow field of the gradients and with this you can have an idea of the direction of the changes of intensities in the images. In the case that flow fields are used in the paper the flow fields maybe can be watched as this

[image]

Other source of information that could help you is [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients)